# Display Label "Install Java Version x.xx"

Tags: java, jvm

I have a desktop Java application. I would like when I start the application without the installed JVM to display some dialog message "Please install Java version x.xx". Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a launcher for your application using something like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). The launcher will be able to display such a message.